# unable to opne pdf file on android 10 using xamarin forms

Tags: android, file, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mime-types

I have a developed code to save and open a pdf file and used to work on all android devices. Recently I figured it is not working on android 10.

Code to Save file:

```
public async void SaveFile(byte[] bytes, string folderPath, string fileName)
    {
            if (IsFileExists(folderPath, fileName))
            {
                DeleteFile(folderPath, fileName);
            }
            string path = GetFilePath(folderPath, fileName); //path = "/storage/emulated/0/3080/TCPS/584"
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName); //filename = "Fugro TCO B-17-009.pdf"
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
        }
    }
```

To Open the file:

```
public void OpenFile(string folderPath, string fileName)
    {
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        string path = GetFilePath(folderPath, fileName);
        string mimeType = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(fileName);
        if (extension != null)
        {
            mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.ToLower());
        }
        newIntent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(GetFile(path, fileName)), mimeType);
        newIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivity(newIntent);
    }
```

Here, if the file is pdf, I'm getting mime-type as null but it's work fine on android 9 and below.
Can anyone explain what needs to be done to get it to work on android 10?

Comment: Could you get the file in the OpenFile method correctly ?

Comment: Yes, i can see the same path in openfile method. While debugging on android 9 and 10, both path's are same.

Comment: Try to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=“true”` to your manifest.

Comment: do i need to change targetsdkversion to 29 to use this setting?

Comment: is there a way to achieve this by not updating target ask version.

Comment: Did it work when you change the targetsdkversion to 29 and add the above codes?If you don't want to change the targetsdkversion ,I think you should  make an SDK judgment, more than 29 needs to use other methods to access the file.

Comment: As my app is already targetting 29 and is in the play store, i dont want to change sdk and release a fix in hurry. Can you help me what adjistments need to be done to able to work on android 10 devices?

Comment: Did it work when adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage=“true”` ?

Comment: It says no resource found as im targeting android 9. Is there a workaround for the apps targetting api 28?

Comment: Did you provide all the permissions needed as shown here https://github.com/SimonSimCity/Xamarin-CrossDownloadManager
You could also message the creators of that plugin on twitter! The list of contributors in on that link